# Does mongoose / mongodb have access to object references in schema during aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a query that reads from 2 different obj referentes inside my mongo database. I will use a simple example of what im looking for.

I have 3 schemas:

```
User = new Schema({
    places:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Place'}],
    shouts:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Shout'}]
});
Place = new Schema({
    name:String,
    description:String,
});
Shout = new Schema({
    content:String,
});
```

My biggest question is if mongoose or mongodb has access to objectId references when executing the aggregate method. Allow me to elaborate.

```
module.exports.askForShoutInPlace = function(req, res){
    var pname = new RegExp(req.params.pname, 'i'); 
    User.aggregate(
        [
           {'$match':{ 'places':{
               '$elemMatch':{'name':pname}
                }
           },
           {'$project':{ shout:'$shouts'} },
           {'$unwind':'$shouts'},
           {'$group':{_id:'$shouts'}}
        ]).exec(function(err, results){
        res.send(results);
    });

}
```

That usually works fine, however I'm getting an empty array once the $match operator is called, im guessing it has to do with the object references returning undefined subobjects. is there any work around this? or does this mean I have to take another route to employ populating?

thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: You may want to read - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. You need to resolve the references in the client side. Mongoose does it for you using the `populate` feature. The `aggregation` code is executed on the server side and hence the references would not be automatically resolved.

Comment: thanks for the reply @BatScream , this is just an example to understand the  fundament of the error, I'm working with geospacial indexes, so working around that on the client side might prove harder than needed. hypothetically, if the child schema would have a refference to the parrent, would  you say it's possible to aggregate the child Schema, to populate the parent and filter afterwards before sending the results to the client? or would this prove to be a terrible performance bottle neck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way to access object Referenced data during the aggregate Process, the work  around I employed for my project was to add a reference to the owner in the schemas in question.

```
User = new Schema({
    places:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Place'}],
    shouts:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Shout'}]
});
Place = new Schema({
    owner:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Place'},
    name:String,
    description:String,
});
Shout = new Schema({
    owner:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Place'},
    content:String,
});
```

And then employed to Aggregate directly on the subdocument to obtain the unique users who own the instances of of place, this way I can obtain a shout result matching a query and a place.

Example:

```
module.exports.askForShoutInPlace = function(req, res){
var pname = new RegExp(req.params.pname, 'i'); 
var stringQ = new RegExp(req.paramos.qcontent, 'i');
Place.aggregate(
    [
       //find Places that match criteria
       {'$match':{'name':pname}},
       //select owner id object to result
       {'$project':{ owner:'$owner'}},
       //group those results to single array with unique ids of users
       {'$group':{_id:'$owner'}}
    ]).exec(function(err, results){
    //find user shouts that match string and belong to owners know to be owners of a place
    Shout.find({'content':stringQ}).where({'owner':{'$in':results}}).exec(function(err, shouts){
       res.send(shouts);
    });
});

}
```

this is just the way I found to work around my particular needs, I hope it might help somebody.