# MongoDB query results aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to aggregate results of multiple searches together.

Currently, we do multiple lookups. For example, first - find user, then using retrieved userid find work order, then for each product ID in the order, lookup full product information.

Can this be aggregated into a single query, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Depends allot on how you handle your schema, so my answer could vary depending on what your specific needs are. however I did post a way on a work around to a similar situation (in a example of 3 schemas) you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235382/does-mongoose-mongodb-have-access-to-object-references-in-schema-during-aggreg).

also it depends on if you have object id references or not, if its all stored directly then it could be a single aggregation query.

Comment: I just need to lookup results across three/four collections. I am extremely new to MongoDB, so it could be that I did not understand your input. Sorry.

Comment: gotcha, I could post a new answer on how I would go about it and hope it helps. are you working on nodejs? do you need strict mongoDB or would [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) opetarions work as well?

Comment: Thank you again for helping. Yes, I am working with Node. We are using Feathers, which can be configured for MongoDB [we will probably use that for production], nedb - one we are using for the development phase. I just joined the team last week. This is the first introduction to Node, for me.